# Why is my HTML form horizontally stacked?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to style my HTML form, and everything is on the same line. From what I understand, everything is supposed to be vertically stacked by default.

I've tried setting the form to display: flex, as well as display: block. The only thing that works is if I use a universal selector. I've tried targeting the body element, the form element, as well as making a div class.

This is the only thing that works:

```
* {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}
```

I want my form to have every input and label on a separate line without using line breaks. It's not happening by default, and when I try to use CSS, it will only work if I use a universal selector.

Comment: Please share the HTML. *`display: block`* items are vertically-stacked by default, but `inline` and `inline-block` items (like inputs and labels) will align adjacently.

Comment: Refer to [A Complete Guide to Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/). Addendum: you might be interested in playing [FLEXBOX FROGGY](https://flexboxfroggy.com).

Answer (score 1):

To achieve the layout you want you need to apply `display: flex; flex-direction: column;` to a div inside your form. I find that sometimes applying styles directly to the form element itself can be messy.

```css
.container{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

input{
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <div class="container">
    <h1>Register</h1>

    <label for="email">Email</label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Email" name="email" required>

    <label for="psw">Password</label>
    <input type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" name="psw" required>

    <label for="psw-repeat">Repeat Password</label>
    <input type="password" placeholder="Repeat Password" name="psw-repeat" required>

    <button type="submit">Register</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to use `display: flex;` then you need to add `flex-wrap: wrap;` to the same element, otherwise everything will be squished on one line.

Additionally, you'll need to set the width of the child elements otherwise they'll stay on the same line.

```css
form {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
label {
  width: 100%; //doesn't have to be 100, but enough to bump the siblings to new lines
}
input {
  width: 100%;
}
```

If you don't want to use `flex`, then add `display: block;` to each element to give it its own line (wouldn't need to add width style).

Are you using a CMS? You may have other styles affecting your elements. I'd open the page in your browser and [Inspect Element](https://www.lifewire.com/get-inspect-element-tool-for-browser-756549) on the form, label and input elements to see what else may be affecting them.